# iPhone: doesn't change views when tilted

Tags: iphone, web-browser

When browsing web pages I like to tilt for landscape view. It seems that I can't get it to rotate the image anymore.

Is there a setting for this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to this question: http://support.apple.com/en-us/TS3805

Make sure that Portrait Orientation Lock is off.

[image: Control Center]